# One2many relationship in Odoo model linked to self can't add record

Tags: odoo, ticket-system, one2many

I'm currently using Odoo 12.0+e-20181025. At the moment I'm using the Helpdesk module and have been trying to modify it so that it can have a child ticket from another ticket. At first, I was just going to make it choose an existing ticket, but then I decided to make it so that it can't choose, but only create a new ticket that will be assigned as its child. The problem is that now it can't do anything. I have been asked to remove the delete function, and I did. I used the studio to unchecked the "Can Delete" checkbox. The trash icon for the delete function is gone, just as intended. But now I can't add new child ticket. It just gave me the following error message:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

I've tried checking the delete option again, but the problem remains. I've tried using my previous database backup,  and found that it is indeed that one action that somehow locked the function. Another thing I've tried is to check the form view while using the studio. It gave the exact same error message.

Here is the snippet from my XML. Any help is appreciated.

````
    <tree string="Tickets">
      <field name="display_name" modifiers="{&quot;readonly&quot;: true}"/>
      <field name="partner_id" on_change="1" can_create="true" can_write="true" modifiers="{}"/>
      <field name="team_id" on_change="1" can_create="true" can_write="true" modifiers="{}"/>
      <field name="user_id" can_create="true" can_write="true" modifiers="{}"/>
      <field name="stage_id" on_change="1" can_create="true" can_write="true" modifiers="{}"/>
      <field name="create_date" modifiers="{&quot;readonly&quot;: true}"/>
    </tree>```
````

Comment: please add some piece of code.

Comment: Could be the Studio view inheritance breaking something. Try going to Settings - Technical - Views, then search name for "studio" and model for helpdesk. If there are results, review them or simply make backup and delete one by one to test.